# BootStrap dropdown options- Restrict TAB key for options change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown implemented in my page. clikcing on dropdown opens the options in select. Up and Down arrow key is used for navigating through options. But 'TAB' key also performs the same options navigation now. Instead i need TAB key to select an option as 'ENTER' key does.

Need to overrride the default action of TAB key. Please advice

Comment: Not sure you can even do this, you could create your own dropdown and use the css from bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help you. It uses jQuery for simplicity.
keyCode 9 intercepts the Tab keypress. preventDefault() on event blocks the normal behaviour of the event generated by the given keypress.

```
$("#myDropdown").on('keydown', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#myDropdown .option").click();
  } 
});
```

Comment: Nice . Can u please explain?

Comment: What is it exactly that you didn't understand?

Comment: Thank you - in my case I applied the keydown function to _.dropdown-menu_ - this correctly disallowed tabbing while in the dropdown.